# Bad Request (#400) - Missing required parameters: id in YII2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to make a CRUD operation using GII Tool, but I get the error message `Missing required parameters: id`, when I try to save my post.

Post controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Post();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->post_create_time=date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_post]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Why do I always get this error?

Comment: Show code of `actionView()`.

Comment: @arogachev this is the `actionView` :

`public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Post();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->post_create_time=date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
        $model->save(false);

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_post]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Make sure that you do `$model->save(false)` and see whether if it works.

Comment: thank you @Abhimanyu, it's work :) but i don't know why. can you explain why `$model->save(false)`. why should `false` ?

Comment: @Shinoda_ When you use `$model->save(false)`, it skips the validation. If this is working for you that means the `rules` that you have mentioned in your `model` are incorrect. Fix your `rules` and try saving your model without `false`. If everything is correct, it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could try here:

- Check whether `$model->post_id` is null before using it.

See example below

```
$success=$model->save();
// if it's false, it means there was an error
var_dump($success);
exit;
```

- Check whether `save()` has been successful before using it:

see below code

```
if($model->save()){
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_post]);
}else{
    // show errors
    var_dump($model->getErrors();
    exit;
}
```

Other than that, I'd advise you to post the code for `actionView` and class `Post` as well

Comment: I've check `save()` and the result is `array(0) { } `. and then whats next ? i still understand what should i do after i check it. i'm newbie with yii. code for `actionView` : `public function actionView($id) { return $this->render('view', [ 'model' => $this->findModel($id), ]); }`

Comment: I've edited the code: you need to attribute the `save()` method to a variable ( I named it `$success` ) and then dump that variable to see whether the saving worked or not.

Comment: I've try, and the result is `bool(false) `

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Post();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->post_create_time=date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
        if($model->save())
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_post]);
        else
            {
            return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $mod`enter code here`el,
            ]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously happens on $this->redirect. Check your url rules in main.php file.
It should be located somewhere here in main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [
      ...
   ]
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Some fields are too short, so it can't store but now show exact error messages.
I increase field size, that's ok.